# Nonblocking ++ equivalent in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

The `++` operator in Systemverilog is blocking.
Is there a nonblocking equivalent to it, or are we bound to use the more verbose `x<=x+1` form if we want to keep it nonblocking?

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.2 Increment and decrement operators:

> These increment and decrement assignment operators behave as blocking
> assignments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no non-blocking equivalent to the `++` operator. It has been suggested for the next revision of the standard.

Comment: Note that the suggestion was rejected for not having enough benefit. https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=7322